# How to find image coordinates on canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

There is a site, not mine
the site has canvas with random appearing images.

All images have the same sizes but random position all the time.

Is it possible to find coordinates of such images and how?

https://ibb.co/vYVGdb4 - image sample

Comment: You can do a capture of the screen and find it by yourself but once the image is drawn on a canvas there is no way to ask the canvas.

Comment: The only way to do this would be to scan for the image. But for that to work, you would need the image. Can you add an example to your post?

Comment: https://ibb.co/vYVGdb4 image

Comment: Dominique Fortin. there are at least 2 programs on python which can find such images. python rules?